# Is there a way to access the profiles stored in my Logitech G700 mouse with a Windows 7 Virtual Machine?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, debian, logitech-mouse

I am running Debian Wheezy and there is not any way (that I know of) to modify the mouse profiles on my Logitech G700 mouse. On this system, I have a Windows 7 virtual machine that I run in Virtual Box, but when I install and run the Logitech Gaming Software, it cannot detect my mouse.

Virtual Box does not recognize the mouse as a USB device, so I can't just pass it through that way and it doesn't matter whether the mouse is plugged in with a cord or with a bluetooth dongle.

Answer (score 2):

So, I had the same issue...until I discovered the answer my self! (Sorry, have to brag about that a little bit after not finding a solution). Check to see if Virtual Box has a "connect to VM" for removable devices. I'm using VMWare and when I right click on my VM, I'm able to choose "Removable Devices ->  Logitech G13 -> Connect (disconnect from host)" This will pass the USB devices through to the VM. Good luck with Virtual Box!

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the problem with the mouse. The G13 is  a different kind of usb device so passing through the USB host doesn't cause any problems. I tried installing VMWare Player to see if you can do the same with the G700 and you can't (you actually can with VirtualBox, but it causes other problems once you install device specific drivers).